# A NullReferenceException exception in System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView

Tags: winforms

I have a .NET 4.0 WinForms application. A Form of the application contains a Grid – an System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView object

Suddenly I have got a (non-reproducible!) NullReferenceException in it. The call stack was the following:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.UnwireEditingControlEvents()
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.EndEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context, DataGridViewValidateCellInternal validateCell, Boolean fireCellLeave, Boolean fireCellEnter, Boolean fireRowLeave, Boolean fireRowEnter, Boolean fireLeave, Boolean keepFocus, Boolean resetCurrentCell, Boolean resetAnchorCell)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetCurrentCellAddressCore(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean setAnchorCellAddress, Boolean validateCurrentCell, Boolean throughMouseClick)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.set_CurrentCell(DataGridViewCell value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnClearingRows()
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.ClearInternal(Boolean recreateNewRow)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.RefreshRows(Boolean scrollIntoView)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.ProcessListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.currencyManager_ListChanged(Object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.List_ListChanged(Object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.InnerList_ListChanged(Object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1.OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1.FireListChanged(ListChangedType type, Int32 index)
   at System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1.ClearItems()
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Clear()
   at <My Code>;
```

The  calls method Clear of a BindingList-derived list. The BindingList-derived list is, in turn, used in a BindingSource object. The  BindingSource object is a datasource of the DataGridView.

I cannot understand – why this happens? And why it happens only sometimes? (to the moment I have seen the problem only once). 
And how can this be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this myself just now. In my case, I noticed it only happens if the grid has more than about 10 rows or so and you immediately try to go to the last row. My workaround was, after setting the `BindingSource`, to manually set the current cell to a cell within the first row:

```
grdConditions.DataSource = myDataSource;
if (grdConditions.Rows.Count > 0)
    grdConditions.CurrentCell = grdConditions[0, grdConditions.RowCount - 1];
```

Seemed to fix the issue for me.